# Group By columnA and get the total value from columnB in php?

Tags: php, csv

given values:

```
columnA     columnB
ball        2
star        1
sun         1
ball        1
star        3
sun         4
ball        1
```

output:

```
columnA     columnB
ball        4
star        4
sun         5
```

is there a way to get the output in a php loop.?
sorry. just a newbie

Comment: `select columnA , sum(columnB)    columnB from thetable group by columnA`

Comment: @meh - in a php sir.

Comment: no sir. im getting the data on csv file

Comment: im using file_get_contents function so it returns string. 

then => 

$field = explode(',',$row); so i now I have two columns

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the CSV looks like this:

```
ball,2
star,1
sun,1
ball,1
star,3
sun,4
ball,1
```

the following should work

```
$handle = fopen("mycsv.csv", "r");
$out = array();

while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    $out[$data[0]] = isset($out[$data[0]]) ? $out[$data[0]] + $data[1] : $data[1];
}
fclose($handle);

foreach($out as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " -> " . $value . "\n";
}
```

Comment: How can I achieve this in php only? im getting the data from csv file

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`. As for the loop, you can use different loops in this case I used `foreach`

```
$sql = "SELECT columnA, SUM(columnB) as columnB
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY columnA
        ORDER BY columnA ASC";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll()

foreach($result as $res){
   var_dump($res);
}
```

Comment: How can I achieve this in php only? im getting the data from csv file

Answer (score 0):

If this is an database you could do something like this:

```
$var = array("ball", "star", "sun");
$all = array();
foreach($var as $v){
  $sql = "Select sum(columnB) from table_name WHERE columnA = " . $v;
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute();
  $result = $sth->fetchAll()
  $all[] $result;
}
```

Edit: tbh the other answers are better than mine. Still this might help u.

Comment: How can I achieve this in php only? im getting the data from csv file